# Facebook app configuration to generate reports for my clients

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I created a really simple Facebook app that simply executes `FacebookRequest`s and retrieves impressions, insights, and post data.

I had to create a Facebook app b/c in order for me to make these requests- I needed an APP ID and an APP SECRET.

I'd like to be able to easily generate reports for my clients' Facebook accounts that I do not directly manage.

What is the best/easiest way for my clients to accept/allow this app's usage?  I don't want a page tab on my clients' accounts, either.  I don't want to broadcast that they are utilizing this service that I setup.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Is this for getting data on a Facebook page?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was manually building a login flow per [Facebook's documention](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1#login).

Once the user authorized my app- it was successfully listed under their [Settings | Apps] section.  Since this user managed the Facebook Page, I could execute FacebookRequests and retrieve impressions, insights, and post data that I had mentioned in my question with the page ID and the access token that the login dialog response provided.